# refresh pagination laravel with axios and datatables

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, axios, datatables

I'm creating a list user table on fw laravel by using datatable and axios (not use vuejs), i don't use datatable's pagination but laravel's one because datatables take a lot of time to respond upon retrieving a million records, I can't find a way to use serverside feature cause axios replace ajax feature in severside. The issue began from this:

I'm successful to use laravel's pagination with js but as it comes to 10 or more page, the pagination not update and change the positive upon i click number page, i only can change a page from 1 to 10, here is my pagination code:
display pagination

```
<div id="pagination">
     {!! $axios->links() !!}
</div>
```

and here is js code

```
$(document).on('click', '.pagination a',function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $('li').removeClass('active');
                    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
              
                    let pg = $(this).attr('href')
                    reloadData(pg)

                    window.history.pushState("", "",pg)
                })
```

reloadData function:

```
 function reloadData(value){
                    axios.get(url+'/data'+ value).then(handleResponse)
                     .catch(function (error) {
                            console.log(error);
                      })
                
                    function handleResponse(response) {
                        data = response.data.data;
                        $('#dataid').DataTable().clear().destroy()
                        $('#dataid').DataTable({
                        paging  : false,
                        severSide: true,
                        processing: true,
                        deferRender: true,
                        order: [],
                        retrieve: true,
                        pagingType: 'full_numbers',
                        dom: 'lBfrtip', 
                        columnDefs: [{
                            "defaultContent": "-",
                            "targets": "_all"
                          }],
                        data: data,
                        columns: [
                        { data: 'name' },
                        { data: 'email' },
                        { data: 'phone'  },
                        { data: '' },
                        { data: 'created_at' },
                        { data: function(data){
                            return  '<td class="pr-0 text-center">'+
                                    '<a id="delete-btn" class="label label-inline label-light-default font-weight-bolder delete-btn" data-id="'+data.id+'" href="javascript:void(0)">Delete'+
                                    '</a>'+ '/'+
                                    '<a id="edit-btn" class="label label-inline label-light-default font-weight-bolder delete-btn" data-id="'+data.id+'" href=" javascript:void(0)">Edit'+
                                    '</a>'+
                                    '</td>'
                        }}
                        ],
                    })
                    }
                }
```

controller :

```
//display view and pagination
public function index(Request $request)
    {   
        $axios = Apiato::call('User@GetAllUsersAction', [$request]);
        $axios->withPath('');
        return view('user::Axios.list',compact('axios'));
    }

// i retrived the records from this
public function getData(Request $request)
    {   
        //$user = $request->getContent();
        //$user = json_decode($user,true);
        $axios = Apiato::call('User@GetAllUsersAction', [$request]);
        return $axios;
    }
```

i expect something like this upon i click number page : [1],2,3,4,5,...,24,25 --> 1,2,...,[6],7,8,9,...25

Comment: What do you see at the moment?

Comment: the number page : 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10...24.25, i cannt go page 11,12,ect,...

Comment: Does the bracketed number change on the numbers you can see, `[1] 2 3 4...` to `1 2 [3] 4...` and so on or is it just drawing the whole list?